# Have any Zoan types other than Chopper gained the ability to transform into more than three things?

Tags: one-piece

Chopper can transform into 7 different things (not including monster point) with the rumble ball and after the timeskip he can transform into 7 more. But why are there no other Zoan types that have more than three transformations!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Chopper can transform into 7 different things (not including monster point) **with the rumble ball**.

You answered your own question right there. He's completely reliant on a drug that he developed in order to make the additional transformations. Before the timeskip he was able to do the original 3 transformations without the rumble ball, and an additional 4 with the rumble ball.

After the timeskip he no longer needs the rumble ball for all 7 original transformations. There is nothing canon that explains why. However with the fact that he is able to transform into Monster Point with only 1 rumble ball now hints that he has developed a permanent effect of some degree that allows this.

It is assumed at this point that Chopper *could* theoretically develop something for other Zoan-class users assuming the rumble ball didn't already work for them. Suffice to say that at this point no other *known* scientists have developed anything similar.

Answer (score 4):

Zoan Devil Fruits allows the user to transform into another species. **This type of fruit provides three basic forms** ([Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Zoan#Effects)):

> - Human Form (人型 Hito-gata?): The user's natural form.
> - Human-Beast Form (人獣型 Jinjū-gata?): A hybrid form, combining both the original and the fruit-bestowed species into an unusual form (usually in a bizarre way where the size is greatly exaggerated).
> - Beast Form (獣型 Kemono-gata?): A fully transformed type.

This is not different from any Zoan user we have seen so far. The thing where Zoan users can get creative is within their Human-Beast form. The Human-Beast form combines both the original and the fruit-bestowed species into an unusual form, but it does not specify which parts are of which species. Zoan users can be creative as to which parts they turn into which species', but **it seems that great control over your Devil Fruit and/or muscles is needed** before you can attempt such feats.

That is why Chopper has been able to discover much of his combinations much sooner on, because **Chopper had been on drugs the whole time**. The rumble ball enhances his control over his Devil Fruit, making him able to experiment more with his different combinations of his Human-Beast hybrid form. He is not the only one that has been able to transform into more than three transformations though.

[image]

While most Zoan Devil Fruits normally allow three forms of transformations under normal circumstances, **Lucci is able to access a fourth form using [Life Return](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Life_Return)** ([Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Neko_Neko_no_Mi,_Model:_Leopard#Usage)). Rob Lucci was seen as one of the strongest Zoan users we have encountered so far, thus it makes sense for him to also be able to manipulate his body further, without the need for drugs.

> Another example we have seen of Zoan users that had transformed further, were the [Jailer Beasts](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Jailer_Beasts). Those five Zoan users, were confirmed to be awakened Zoan users by Crocodile. Assuming Chopper's monster point is his [Awakened](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Zoan#Awakening) form, it is again shown, that **Chopper could access his awakened transformation earlier on than other users due to him being on drugs**.

Therefore, at this point it seems that Thebluefish is correct in saying that Chopper can transform into different forms prematurely due to his Rumble ball. Though, **I do not agree on the fact that the rumble would supposedly be necessary in order to gain different transformation. It just greatly enhanced it progression.**

Comment: Yes zoan users have three basic forms as you said, but awakening cannot be considered as a form. Every type of DF can awakened. It provides further capabilities, but as of know it not not mentioned that it is a different form of a Zoan fruit.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Awakened_Zoan#Effects):

> Zoan Devil Fruits allows the user to transform into another species. This type of fruit provides three basic forms:
>
> - **Human Form** (人型 Hito-gata): The user's natural form.
> - **Human-Beast Form** (人獣型 Jinjū-gata): A hybrid form, combining both the original and the fruit-bestowed species into an unusual form (usually in a bizarre way where the size is greatly exaggerated).
> - **Beast Form** (獣型 Kemono-gata): A fully transformed type.

This is not different from any Zoan user we have seen so far. The thing where Zoan users can get creative is within their Human-Beast form. The Human-Beast form combines both the original and the fruit-bestowed species into an unusual form, but it does not specify which parts are of which species. Zoan users can be creative as to which parts they turn into which species', but it seems that great control over your Devil Fruit and/or muscles is needed before you can attempt such feats.

That is why Chopper has been able to discover much of his combinations much sooner on because Chopper had been on drugs the whole time. The rumble ball enhances his control over his Devil Fruit, making him able to experiment more with the different combinations of his Human-Beast hybrid form. He is not the only one that has been able to transform into more than three transformations
though.

Answer (score 0):

After the  time skip Chopper is able to access all the transformations without the rumble ball. The Monster Chopper transformation he unlocks when he eats three can be done with one now, though he is still incapacitated after using it. Not only that. He can control himself while in Monster Chopper form.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Luffy's devil fruit, the "Hito Hito no Mi Model: Nika" is a mythical zoan fruit that allows him to transform into 5 gears. Luffy's Gear 4 has three subforms, Boundman, Snakeman, and Tankman. Counting all his gears apart from gear 4, he has 4 transformations. If we add the three subforms, we get 7 total transformations. So, Chopper and Luffy have the same amount of transformations.